# How can I move files that have different file format to folder which is the same file name?

Tags: python, shutil

First of all, I'm going to use python I consider use shutil  package module.
Second, there are 5 formats and about 20 file names

I made the code

```
import os
imort shutil
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.today().strftime("%m%d")
folder = ['elephant', 'lion', 'dog', 'cat' ...]
format = ['jpg', 'xlsx', 'txt', 'pdf', 'pptx']
for x in folder:
    os.makedirs(f'C:/Users/user/Desktop/animal/{date}/{x}')
    for y in format:
        source = f'C:/Users/user/Desktop/animal/example/{x}.{y}'
```

For now, code that I made but I can't add the code which can move the 5 files that each right folder
For example, lion.jpg, lion.xlsx, lion.txt, lion.pdf, lion.pptx need to move lion folder
What code can I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.today().strftime("%m%d")

folders = ['elephant', 'lion', 'dog', 'cat']
extensions = ['jpg', 'xlsx', 'txt', 'pdf', 'pptx']

root = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop'
for folder in folders:
    # Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist yet
    dst = os.path.join(root, 'animal', date, folder)
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)

    for extension in extensions:
        # Move the file to the destination folder if the file exists
        src = os.path.join(root, 'animal', 'example', f'{folder}.{extension}')
        if os.path.isfile(src):
            shutil.move(src, dst)
```